# Sorting array with multiple fields in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Consider the below hash

```
[
{:rank => 3, :time => "3.00 AM" , :name => "JJJ"},
{:rank => 1, :time => "3.05 AM" , :name => "AAA"},
{:rank => 5, :time => "2.55 AM" , :name => "XXX"},
{:rank => 2, :time => "3.10 AM" , :name => "BBB"}
]
```

How do i sort the fields in an order, so that i will obtain result
as like query 
**(Consider if we fetch values in has is from a table)**

```
select * from my_table order by rank, time, name
```

Please comment if i am not clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a = [
{:rank => 3, :time => "3.00 AM" , :name => "JJJ"},
{:rank => 1, :time => "3.05 AM" , :name => "AAA"},
{:rank => 5, :time => "2.55 AM" , :name => "XXX"},
{:rank => 2, :time => "3.10 AM" , :name => "BBB"}
]
res = a.sort_by{|t| [t[:rank], t[:time], t[:name]]}
```

Comment: Thanks izomorphius... as i am having time field as string, time sorting is not working.. any solution for this?

Comment: You could use the Chronic gem:  `res = a.sort_by{|t| [t[:rank], Chronic.parse(t[:time]), t[:name]]}`

Comment: izomorphius thanks for the answer..
but what should i do to sort the time field in either direction..
if i tried to give like `res = a.sort_by{|t| [t[:rank], -t[:time], t[:name]]}` it throws an error!! any suggestions..?

Comment: @cometbalan a few suggestions can be found here:  http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/224672 I do not know of any really short way to do that.